# How is the line/page size for HTML scrollbars determined

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a div with a vertical scrollbar containing mixed content. Some plain text, images, tables, some other visual markup.

There seems to be a couple of points scrolling down the page where it gets "stuck" in Chrome (also tested Firefox, it seemed slightly slower at that point, but not broken), with the scroll wheel or up/down arrows only moving a couple of pixels at a time. I have no listeners for the scroll events on this page.

How do web browsers decide how fast to scroll at various points when dealing with mixed/complex content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this could be a performance issue with the rendering of components. I recommend using the [Timeline](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/timeline) feature in Chrome Developer Tools to capture the performance information and go from there.

Comment: Think you are maybe right, Chrome shows some long 300+ms frames due to other reasons in those areas, I hadn't thought about (they don't effect the layout, but do touch the DOM), and having got rid of them no longer have a noticeable problem. Still not sure why it has such an effect though, rather than it just jumping say 50px at a time instead of rendering a smooth scroll.